# How to umount a USB drive?

Tags: mount, usb-drive

I want to know how to `umount` my USB drive via command line. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit.

Comment: Have you looked at `man umount`?

Comment: Do you want to umount it via commandline or using a graphical interface?

Comment: via command-line

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Suppose your usb drive is mounted to `/media/usb` then it would be sufficient to do

```
sudo umount /media/usb
```

Suppose the your usb is `/dev/sdb1` then you could also do

```
sudo umount /dev/sdb1
```

You may also have a look at the anwers of one of my questions, how to umount all attached usb devices with a single command: [Umount all attached usb disks with a single command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43594/umount-all-attached-usb-disks-with-a-single-command)

Comment: The command `sudo fdisk -l` can be helpful if you don't know where a drive is mounted.

Comment: That's `umount`, not `uNmount`, in case anyone else is wondering why the command is not recognized.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use

```
udisks --unmount /dev/sdb1
```

which does not require root.

---

For macOS:

```
diskutil umount /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: This is the what I was looking for. Do the same unprivileged action the desktop does for mounting the device. TIL.

Comment: udisks command is changed to udisksctl in debian derivatives (available in 'udisks2' package). `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1`

Comment: Don't forget to power down the USB stick as well:
`udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdb1 && udisksctl power-off -b /dev/sdb`

Answer (score 3):

Better than using `sudo` to unmount as root, just install the pmount package and do:

```
pumount /media/usb
```

As `man pumount` says:

```
NAME
       pumount - umount arbitrary hotpluggable devices as normal user

SYNOPSIS
       pumount [ options ] device

DESCRIPTION
       pumount  is  a wrapper around the standard umount program which permits
       normal users to umount removable devices without a matching  /etc/fstab
       entry.
```

Comment: no `pumount` on my system, none in my package repo to install, either.

Comment: @michael_n Do you have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit, as in the OP question?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 -- at some point, pumount must either have been deprecated, did it come from a 3rd party repo?

Comment: I see it -- one has to install `pmount` (which is why `pumount` wasn't matched when searching in in the package manager). http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/pumount.1.html

Comment: @michael_n thanks, I've added mention of the package to help others in future.